# how to load from a CSV file with multiple symbols containing OHLCV using getSymbols and date in YYYYMMDD

Tags: r, csv, xts, quantmod

I am relatively new to R and in here. I am trying to read in a CSV file that has multiple symbols with OHLCV and date in string YYYYMMDD format

[Data format example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmgCo.png)

I have tried:

```
data <- read.csv(file="DFM.csv", sep=",", dec=".", header=TRUE, col.names = c("Symbols", "Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> class(data)
[1] "data.frame"
> head(data)
  Symbols     Date Open High  Low Close   Volume
1     DIB 20160630 5.03 5.12 5.03  5.11  6171340
2     DIB 20160629 5.10 5.11 5.02  5.02  5241741
3     DIB 20160628 5.05 5.11 5.02  5.07  5258839
4     DIB 20160627 5.01 5.11 5.01  5.03  5038589
5     DIB 20160626 4.94 5.04 4.90  5.02 10593471
6     DIB 20160623 5.14 5.14 5.09  5.12  3069970

as.Date(data$Date, format="%Y%m%d") # didn't work
```

Somehow I need to load it in `getSymbols()` so I can use `chart_Series()` to plot the charts. Can anyone help?

Comment: You don't need to use getSymbols() to use chart_Series().  Use an xts object with chart_Series.   What do you mean by as.Date(...) #didn't work?  Are you trying to make an `xts` object?  If you offered a minimal set of data in a more friendly format relevant to your problem (e.g. data.frame(time = c('20161023', "20150502"), x = c(2, 3))) someone is likely to offer a solution quickly.

Comment: Actually, I managed to find the solution to convert the date format in the data.frame using ...data$Date <- as.Date(as.character(data$Date), format="%Y%m%d"). Now I have all the date.frame in the format SDOHLCV. But now, I need to see how I can produce chart_Series()

Answer (score 0):

Using your example data this is one possible solution to import the file, convert the `Date` column, split the file by `Symbol` and arrange it in a way to chart the individual objects(stocks) in a straightforward way:

First and last 3 lines of original file data (allStocks):

```
> both(allStocks)
  Symbol     Date Open High  Low Close   Volme
1    DIB 20160630 5.03 5.12 5.03  5.11 6171340
2    DIB 20160629 5.10 5.11 5.02  5.02 5241741
3    DIB 20160628 5.05 5.11 5.02  5.07 5258839
   Symbol     Date Open High Low Close Volme
16    CBD 20160627  5.6  5.6 5.6   5.6     0
17    CBD 20160626  5.6  5.6 5.6   5.6     0
18    CBD 20160623  5.6  5.6 5.6   5.6     0
```

Lets's start by converting the Date column:

```
allStocks$Date <- as.Date(as.character(allStocks$Date), format="%Y%m%d")
```

Next, split `allStocks` by `Symbol` which gives you a list where each list element represents an individual stock with name `Symbol` :

```
allStocks <- split(allStocks,allStocks$Symbol)
```

Next, get rid of the `Symbol` column to prepare for a xts object:

```
allStocks <- lapply(allStocks, function(x) as.xts(x[,3:7],order.by=x[,2]))
```

and finally convert the list into individual xts-objects each representing a stock with name `Symbol`:

```
list2env(allStocks,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

You should now have 3 nicely formatted objects in your GlobalEnvironment ready to be charted.

i.e. `str` and first,last lines of stock `DIB`:

```
> str(DIB)
An ‘xts’ object on 2016-06-23/2016-06-30 containing:
  Data: num [1:6, 1:5] 5.14 4.94 5.01 5.05 5.1 5.03 5.14 5.04 5.11 5.11 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "Open" "High" "Low" "Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL

> both(DIB)
           Open High  Low Close    Volme
2016-06-23 5.14 5.14 5.09  5.12  3069970
2016-06-26 4.94 5.04 4.90  5.02 10593471
2016-06-27 5.01 5.11 5.01  5.03  5038539
           Open High  Low Close   Volme
2016-06-28 5.05 5.11 5.02  5.07 5258839
2016-06-29 5.10 5.11 5.02  5.02 5241741
2016-06-30 5.03 5.12 5.03  5.11 6171340
```